# Will Windows 7 run on ASUS PANDIT P1?

Tags: windows-7

I installed a trial version of windows  7 but was not able to get the sound working?

I did search the net and the ASUS official website for sound drivers for window 7 but was not able to find any!

what should i do, the seller told me that it can support 64-bit versions also so windows 7 is no big deal!!

help, thanku

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Asus Pundit was a low-end, bare-bones PC built for Windows 2000 -> XP era. If neither Asus nor Windows Update provide you a compatible audio driver, chances are not good that you'll get Audio working under Win7.

Note that Vista & Win7 both cut support for quite a lot of legacy hardware which required custom drivers and weren't supported by their chipset/device manufacturer.

Comment: so whats the solution i need the audio working please?